# Using Terraform with AWS Tagging Policies Enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, terraform, devops

i have enabled Tag Policies on my AWS where any resources created has to have mandatory tags pre-set on the policy. E.G Department: HR, Finance. On the management console of course it prompts me for entering a tag otherwise the resource wont be made.

I also utilize terraform to stand resources. Within my terrafor.tf script do i need to include the aws tagging syntax and code within my script? e.g :

```
tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you have enabled tagging policies? Is it through AWS Config rule or any custom scripts/Lambda etc?

Comment: Its via AWS Organisations then Policies.

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform AWS provider has a new feature called **default_tags** that will automatically assign your tags to any AWS resource created by Terraform.

An example usage from Terraform 1.0 :

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      Name     = "Hello World"
      project  = "Hello Project"
    }
  }
}
```

See more details about it in this article I wrote here:
[Best Practice for Terraform AWS Tags](https://blog.rocketinsights.com/best-practices-for-terraform-aws-tags/)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

Since, tags can be represented as `map` datatype which maps tag-names to tag-value. Therefore, we can do something like this:

```
tags = {
    "tag-name-1" = "value-1"
    "tag-name-2" = "value-2"
 }
```

Comment: So in essence your answer is i do need to include the tagging syntax in my terraform script?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest even more syntax... We often do

```
tag {
  key = "Name"
  value = "${var.groupid}-${var.stackid}"
  propagate_at_launch = true
}
tag {
  key = "Email"
  value = "${var.tagemail}"
  propagate_at_launch = true
}
tag {
  key = "Environment"
  value = "${var.tagenvironment}"
  propagate_at_launch = true
}
```

I think you'll want to have "propagate_at_launch" set for each one.